# onLocationChanged() starts too late and I can't get the latitude and longitude on time

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm trying to use onLocationChanged() method to get the latitude and longitude of the phone but the method execute too late and the vars contains 0.0 at the JsonRequest, any idea what can I do to start the onLocationChangedMethod before the onCreate()?

there is my code:

```
  package weatheralarm.valbol.oshrim.final_alarmproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PresentWeatherAdvice extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    final String PATH = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=";
    final String GPSPATH = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=";
    final String GPSPATH1 = "&lon=";
    final String SUFFIX = "&units=metric&mode=json&appid=f69e8280457b8e7fe2e954aae1444";
    private final int DISTANCE = 5, AFTERMILLISECS = 100;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private ArrayList<Weather> listArr;
    String url;
    private double latitude, longitude;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    private final String PREFSNAME = "alarmClockSet";
    private final String LONKEY = "lonKey";
    private final String LATKEY = "latKey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_present_weather_advice);
        prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFSNAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //request udpate if user changed location or after time
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, AFTERMILLISECS, DISTANCE, (LocationListener) this);
     //   latitude = Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString(LATKEY,"0.0"));
      //  longitude = Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString(LONKEY,"1.1"));
        url = GPSPATH + latitude + GPSPATH1 + longitude + SUFFIX;
        Log.i("url","url: " + url + " lat " + latitude);
        //getWeather(url, this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getWeather(url,this);
    }

    private void getWeather(String url,Context context){

        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        Log.i("url", url);
        Log.i("TAG", "lati-getW" + latitude);

        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String icon, date, temp, desc, iconPath;
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("list");


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject dt = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.i("dt " + i + " ", dt.toString());
                                date = dt.getString("dt_txt");
                                Log.i("date", date);
                                icon = dt.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("icon");
                                iconPath = " http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png";
                                Log.i("icon", icon);
                                desc = dt.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("description");
                                Log.i("desc", desc);
                                temp = dt.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp");
                                Log.i("temp", temp);
                                Weather weather = new Weather(iconPath, date, temp, desc);
                                listArr.add(weather);
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < listArr.size(); i++) {
                                Log.i("TAG", "ListArr: " + listArr.get(i).getDate());

                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("in location", " lat " + latitude +" lon "+ longitude);
        this.longitude = location.getLongitude();
        this.latitude = location.getLatitude();
        Log.i("in location", " lat " + latitude +" lon "+ longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting for your variables `latitude` and `longitude` to be updated you can use [`getLastLocation`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#getLastLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) which will return the best most recent location available. You cannot rely on `onLocationChanged` to be updated (or you can chose to fire your `JsonObjectRequest` inside it) as it will be called only when a new location is available and depending on the device and its sensors the later can be called anytime.